# Using ISBLANK with SUMIF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am doing a summary table which references another page with VLOOKUP formula responses.

Currently using `=SUM('CURRENT'!$J:$J)` to calculate the total numerical values in column J, however there are some values which are #N/A as there is no source data.

This then returns no sum total calculations.

I was wondering the best way to incorporate the IF formula into a SUM formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to persuade Excel to ignore the `#N/A`s and hence get the expected result with `=SUMIF('CURRENT'!J:J,"<>#N/A")`.

The syntax is =SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range) but here the `sum_range` is the `range` so need not be entered ("If this range is omitted, the first range is summed instead.")

The criteria `"<>#N/A"` is that the summation should only apply to cells where their content is not equal (`<>`) to `#N/A`.

Comment: Hi pnuts, i tried this but with no luck, it still returns N/A has the overall calculation. Does it have something to do with the fact that the #N/A value (and all other values in column J) are the result of a VLOOKUP formula

Comment: It still returns #N/A as the total

Comment: Hi pnuts, i deleted the whole formula and started from scratch and this time it worked.

Comment: I think you eluded to the problem in your 1st response. I was summing all of column J, which happened to have 2 heading rows. When i changed thew formula to J3:J450 it resolved.

Comment: With the "<>#N/A" formula though, what logic does it express exactly?

Comment: Hi pnuts is it possible to incorporate the "<>#N/A" in a VLOOKUP formula? As an example i currently have a formula VLOOKUP(O301,'Submission 2013-02-19'!$C$11:$D$508,2,FALSE)*1000, which returns no found values. IN my summary page it cant sum the columns as there are approx 50 #N/a entries